# Pandas dataframe output

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the following Pandas data frame created.

```
#usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd 
vals       = [  1  ,   2  ,   3  ]
ctry_grp   = ['USA', 'USA', 'USA']
state_grp  = ['MA' , 'MA' ,  'CT' ]
country_mean = pd.DataFrame(
    {'values': vals,'country': ctry_grp,'state': state_grp
    }).groupby(['country']).mean()
print(country_mean)
state_mean = pd.DataFrame(
    {'values': vals,'country': ctry_grp,'state': state_grp
    }).groupby(['country','state']).mean()
print(state_mean)
```

The output for country_mean in the above code is in the format of

```
             values
country        
USA           2
```

I want to get the output in the format of [2  , 2  , 2]

The output for state_mean for above code is in the format of

```
               values
country state        
USA     CT        3.0
        MA        1.5
```

I want to get the output in the format of 
[1.5, 1.5, 3]

Please help to modify the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi... your formatting appears to be off. Also, it is unclear what the process is that you are following to get those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': vals,'country': ctry_grp,'state': state_grp})
state_mean = df.groupby('state').transform('mean')  # [1.5, 1.5, 3]
country_mean = df.groupby('country').transform('mean')  # [2, 2, 2]
```

Reading more about [the different ways to apply a function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) to a Groupby object in the docs will give you some good intuitions in cases like this.

Comment: @Maa glad it helped... Please mark an answer as correct [if it resolved your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This helps us keep track of which questions are left to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the original dataframe with the results:

```
columns = ["country"]
df.set_index(columns).join(df.groupby(columns).mean(), rsuffix="_mean")
#        state  values  values_mean
#country                           
#USA        MA       1            2
#USA        MA       2            2
#USA        CT       3            2

columns = ["country", "state"]
df.set_index(columns).join(df.groupby(columns).mean(), rsuffix="_mean")
#               values  values_mean
#country state                     
#USA     CT          3          3.0
#        MA          1          1.5
#        MA          2          1.5
```

Note that the code for calculating the averages is the same in both cases.